# Does Computer always calculate two numbers at a time?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, calculation

I was reading a book named "How to Solve It by Computer" by RG Dromey. In that book content named *Summation of a Set of Numbers* portray that, computer's arithmetic unit works through adding only two numbers at a time. For example, 
if our task is to add 3 numbers and assign it to a variable called sum 
 then computer will add first two numbers then assign that to variable sum after that it will count the final value of sum with the other numbers. Just like ,

```
sum = n1+n2+n3 
sum = n1+n2 +(hold)
sum = sum+n3 // here sum will be computed from the second step
```

By posting this topic here, I just want to know that **is computer performs all the arithmetic calculation task(subtract,multiplication, divide) in that way ?** Or there are something modern technologies that provides doing calculation of multiple numbers at a time ?

Comment: Modern processors also provide [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "it depends on what kind of computer you're using."

Historically, many popular processors worked exactly in the way described above. The processor had hardware that specifically did arithmetic operations on individual numbers or on pairs of numbers. The advantage of this approach is simplicity of processor design - you only need to design circuitry that takes in pairs of numbers as input rather than, say, bigger circuits that can take in larger quantities of numbers. Plus, any sum of more than two numbers can be broken down into a series of additions of exactly two numbers. Because the circuits are simpler, in many cases it's either cheaper to produce the processor, or the processor could be run faster.

The disadvantage of this approach is that you have to issue several addition operations to the processor in order to get the processor to add a list of multiple numbers. As a result, some processors started introducing instructions that allow for more than two values to be added, multiplied, etc. at once. These operations typically require some sort of setup to get the values all loaded into the processor at once, which means that they usually are used only in cases where very large number of numbers will be operated on at once.

Other developments in computer design also allow the computer to operate on multiple numbers at once. For example, multicore processors can have multiple different parallel computations going on at once. It might be the case that each core can only add pairs of numbers at a time, or it might be the case that each core can operate on multiple numbers at once. Graphics cards work in a different way, having huge numbers of cores that all execute in lockstep with one another.

So overall, I'd say that the claim made is not 100% true, but also isn't a bad approximation of how most computers work most of the time. It's good for learning how to think about how the computer processes data, even if it isn't literally the truth.